# SQL Range join (not between)

Tags: sql, range, between

I'm try to select all ports from another table that has port_start and port_end columns.

Let's assume I have ports table is called Ports and the table with range is called Whitelist.

So, It looks something like

```
Ports
-----
 80
120
700

Whitelist
---------
  1 - 100
381 - 500
```

Let's focus on port 80, I thought of selecting what is between the whitelist and then ignore it by using not in/except/whatsoever with between clause.

With not between it will no select the opposite since I need to assure all ranges doesnt fit with the port.

Is there any nice solution to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select p.*
  from ports p
  left join whitelist w
    on p.id between w.port_start and w.port_end
 where w.port_start is null
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b37a3/1/0

Comment: He says "that has port_start and port_end columns". ("columns" plural)